# Can どれ mean plain what/who without selection?

Tags: translation, word-choice, manga

In a comic book (犬夜叉) I found a plain

> どれ…

in a situation when a person sees that something bad happened. Somebody got injured and the spectator apparently asks, who could have possibly done this. I am just wondering why it’s どれ and not だれ or なに. It is a completely unexpected event and there are no offenders to be picked from.

Is どれ used this way? The closest I could find was an example in a dictionary

> 「缶を開けて。」「どれで。」

But that didn’t satisfy me enough.

Another option is that I got the meaning completely wrong or that it’s not the same „what“ どれ.

[image: 犬夜叉]

Comment: Oh. A possible duplicate of my own question. :( And I _was_ thinking about the other meaning of どれ!

Comment: Okay. Since this was confirmed as a duplicate of my earlier question, I think that the どれ there means again something like „let me see“. If somebody reads this and thinks I’m mistaken, please let me know.